# In Python2.7 how to use variables from main script and other user defined functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, variables, global-variables

A bit background of the problem. I am writing a code in Python2.7 which is working fine. But I decided to break it into modules for usability and maintenance purposes which is new to me hence getting some issues. Although I have been able to make it work through hit and trial method but not sure if it is right approach or not hence sharing it here. Code shared here is simplified replication of the real code driving same logic, order and approach.

MainEx.py is the script running at the highest level

```
from LogIn_1 import LogIn
global NumTry
NumTry = 2
LogIn()
# xx is here just to show NumTry variable is further used in MainEx script
xx = NumTry*3
```

Basically what I a trying to communicate here is the NumTry variable is used in MainEx.py (the script at highest level) and also inside LogIn() function. And will also be used by other functions which I am creating.

LogIn_1.py is a user defined function

```
def LogIn():
   from MainEx import NumTry
   # following are some computations involving NumTry
   print NumTry
```

Running MainEx.py gives outcome:

```
2
2
```

Questions:
1. Not sure why it is generating result twice
2. It seems odd, MainEx importing LogIn_1 and LogIn_1 importing MainEx. Kind of ping pong situation importing variables from each other.

I am able to right outcome with following changes:
MainEx.py

```
from LogIn_1 import LogIn
global NumTry
NumTry = 2
#LogIn()
# xx is here just to show NumTry variable is further used in MainEx script
xx = NumTry*3
```

LogIn_1.py

```
def LogIn():
   from MainEx import NumTry
   # following are some computations involving NumTry
   print NumTry
LogIn()
```

Running MainEx.py gives outcome:

```
2
```

I am trying to understand the best practices to avoid future problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a bunch of print statements to your code, you can follow the gory details:

```
# MainEx.py
print 'MainEx: start'
from LogIn_1 import LogIn
print 'MainEx: after Login import'
global NumTry
NumTry = 2
print 'MainEx: before Login() call'
LogIn()
print 'MainEx: after Login() call'
xx = NumTry*3
print 'MainEx: finish'

# LogIn_1.py
print 'start LogIn_1'
def LogIn():
    print '  Login(): start'
    from MainEx import NumTry
    print '  Login(): after MainEx import'
    print NumTry
    print '  Login(): finish'
print 'finish LogIn_1'
```

Output:

```
MainEx: start
start LogIn_1
finish LogIn_1
MainEx: after Login import
MainEx: before Login() call
  Login(): start
MainEx: start                        # Code in MainEx running again!
MainEx: after Login import
MainEx: before Login() call
  Login(): start
  Login(): after MainEx import
2
  Login(): finish
MainEx: after Login() call
MainEx: finish
  Login(): after MainEx import
2
  Login(): finish
MainEx: after Login() call
MainEx: finish
```

As you can see, combining (a) circular imports with (b) code having top-level side effects leads to perverse results. In particular, when `from MainEx import NumTry` runs in the `Login()` call, it appears that Python has to re-execute the code in `MainEx`, since that module doesn't yet have a `NumTry` attribute, leading to double printing. I wasn't really expecting this outcome ... but there it is.

Best practice suggestions:

- Put your import statements at the top of your modules, not inside functions or classes.
- Design your code to avoid circular imports. Your program's modules end up having a kind of hierarchy: your low level modules import nothing from your own code base; and your higher level modules import your lower level modules.
- Design your modules so that nothing **happens** at their top levels. Modules should do nothing more than define classes, define functions, assign constants, or import lower-level modules. Only your system's primary module should do something -- and that something should be to invoke your top-level function (passing in any command-line args), and even that invocation should be conditional, as sketched here:

  ```
  import sys

  def main(args):
      ...

  def foo():
      ...

  def bar():
      ...

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main(sys.argv[1:])
  ```

Comment: thanks @FMc, although I resorted back to one big program, but this is helpful and will keep learning the module approach